# PHP add class to html div

Tags: php, addclass

i would like to add a class to my html (.complete) with php:

```
if( get_field('to-do-repeater') )
{
    Add (complete) class to <div class="to-do to-do-wrap"> should be <div class="to-do to-do-wrap complete">
}
else
{
    Do nothing
}
```

Comment: there is already a div `code <div class="to-do to-do-wrap"></div>` i would like to add a new class name to it whit php called complete. I am using wordpress advanced custom fields true or false ( [link] http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/true-false/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<div class="to-do to-do-wrap<?php echo get_field('to-do-repeater') ? ' complete' : '' ?>"></div>
```

Comment: if( get_field('to-do-repeater') )
{
    Add (complete) class to <div class="to-do to-do-wrap"> should be <div class="to-do to-do-wrap complete">
}

Comment: this is HTML and in it there is a php tag (<?php ?>) . Replace your code with this one I wrote

Comment: yes it is working super perfectly now thanks so much Yazmat : )

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

echo "<div class=\"to-do to-do-wrap ";
if(get_field('to-do-repeater'))
{
    echo "complete";
}
echo " \"></div>";

?>
```

Comment: this is not working it is adding a new div i would like to only add a complete class name to an already existing div : )

Comment: You can remove the existing div that has the classes "to-do to-do-wrap" and replace it with my code.

Comment: ooh yes that's true now it is working too thanks PriestVallon : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: `

```html
<div class="to-do to-do-wrap <?php if(get_field('to-do-repeater') echo "complete"?>">
```