# How to use jQuery to add "active" class to first "div.content"? (and include it in existing script)

Tags: php, jquery

I need to add an active class to the following div tag:

```
<div id="panel1" class="content table-scroll [active]">...</div>
```

I'm not sure how to go about this, but I saw a similar question here [PHP add class to html div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852425/php-add-class-to-html-div) but I'm not really understanding that.

I was using jQuery before, but it wasn't working for me. I have this code which toggles the text in an A tag on click:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    function toggleText() {
        $('dl.accordion div.content.active').prev().find('span.click').text('click to close');
        $('dl.accordion div.content:not(.active)').prev().find('span.click').text('click to open');
    }
    toggleText();
    $('dl.accordion').on("click", "dd a", function (event) {
        setTimeout(toggleText, 25);
    })
});
</script>


$("dl.accordion div.content:first-child").addClass("active"); // not sure where to add this or if it will even work (it didn't work by itself in a dom ready)
```

Here is the actual code if needed (as you can see I'm manually adding the active class here):

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
<dd>
<a href="#panel1">March, 2014 <span class="click hide-for-small-only show-for-medium-up">click to open</span></a>
<div id="panel1" class="content table-scroll active">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%">Date</th>
                <th width="25%">Days</th>
                <th width="25%">Time</th>
                <th width="10%">Register</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>March 1st, 4th, April 1st, 4th</td>
                <td>Tuesdays</td>
                <td>6pm to 9:30pm</td>
                <td class="button-center"><a href="register.html" class="button tiny radius">Register</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>March 1st, 4th, April 1st, 4th</td>
                <td>Long Weekends</td>
                <td>9am to 2:45pm</td>
                <td class="button-center"><a href="register.html" class="button tiny radius">Register</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</dd>
</dl>
```

Any ways jQuery wasn't doing the trick so I'm interested in doing it with PHP as well, I have a list of DD tags on the page within the DL tag, so I only need the active class to be applied to the first DD. I'll be using a CMS to add and remove these so I can't manually add the active class anymore or use the ID tag as that will be changing too.

All help is appreciated, thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    function toggleText() {
        $('dl.accordion div.content.active').prev().find('span.click').text('click to close');
        $('dl.accordion div.content:not(.active)').prev().find('span.click').text('click to open');
    }
    toggleText();
    $('dl.accordion').on("click", "dd a", function (event) {
        setTimeout(toggleText, 25);
    });

    $("div.content:first").addClass('active'); // This is the change.
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QCna7/

Comment: Should I include that in a DOM ready? I'm not sure where to put that in my existing script. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes you need put it at the end of your DOM ready. If it doesn't work we need more code, probably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Your answer actually worked for me, I think it was the difference between first-child and just first lol, thanks! Would you want to attempt to include that into the original script I had?

Answer (score 1):

Use `first` not `first-child`,

Replace

```
$("dl.accordion div.content:first-child").addClass("active");
```

With

```
$("dl.accordion div.content:first").addClass("active");
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/GGDUn/)**

Comment: Where should I include that in the script? I just edited that part of my question because I realized I had the addclass as part of the function that was triggered onclick, so I'm not sure where to go from there! Technically your script shouldn't make any difference though - I can't use the ID because that will change. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Try `$("dl.accordion div.content:first").addClass("active");` Answer updated

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the other person did the same thing. I don't suppose you want to try adding that into the original code I have?

Comment: I have updated the answer with instruction what to replace, http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/GGDUn/