# Add different classes to label and value and output on same line

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I'm trying to add different classes to the label and value so i can style them differently but need to do 2 things.

1. Add a line border-bottom which extends underneath both
2. display the label name and value on the same line

Here's the PHP i'm working with

```
$output .= '<div class="property-details">';

foreach ( (array) $this->property_details as $label => $key ) {
$output .= sprintf( '<div class="label">%s</div><div class="value">%s</div>', $label, $value ) );
        }
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```

This gives me this :

Price:

**10,000,000**

What i need is this

Price: **10,000,000**

Name : **Value**

So each label and value display inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels more like a `CSS` question: I would style the output with a flex container to house all `property-details` items, and a flex container on each `property-details` as well. The outer container creates a stacked, vertical alignment using `flex-direction: column` and the inner flex items keep both `div`s on the same line using the flex's default row direction.

[image]

```css
.property-details-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.property-details {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.property-details .value {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="property-details-container">
  <div class="property-details">
    <div class="label">Price</div>
    <div class="value">10,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="property-details">
    <div class="label">Year Built</div>
    <div class="value">1982</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5q4c30j/3/)

Comment: Yes works but it also involves PHP because i need to modify the default markup.

Comment: @Dev True, you'd have to add the wrapper div to the `PHP`. I say, keep the inline styles clean and add more `CSS`. This is how you scale things properly.

Comment: Agree but what do you think of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389750/4643292 which works once you wrap each detail in a div?

Comment: Also, what if i wanted to added a unique class to each detail for each label and value? How do i do this using foreach?

Comment: @Dev My PHP skill is admittedly very poor. but it seems you could do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852517/949217

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$output .= '<div class="property-details">';

foreach ( (array) $this->property_details as $label => $key ) {
$output .= sprintf( '<div class="label" style="display: inline-block;">%s</div><div class="value" style="display: inline-block;">%s</div>', $label, $value ) );
        }
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```

Though unless you're using some library like Bootstrap I encourage you to use `span` instead:

```
$output .= '<div class="property-details">';

foreach ( (array) $this->property_details as $label => $key ) {
$output .= sprintf( '<span class="label" >%s</span ><span class="value">%s</span >', $label, $value ) );
        }
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```

Use `br` tags for multilines:

```
$output .= '<div class="property-details">';

foreach ( (array) $this->property_details as $label => $key ) {
$output .= sprintf( '<span class="label" >%s</span ><span class="value">%s</span > <br>', $label, $value ) );
        }
$output = substr_replace($output , '', strrpos($output , '<br>'), 4);
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```

Comment: The problem with both of these is they display ALL the labels and values on the same line. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Dev Use `br` tags for multilines. see my updated answer

Comment: Better but doesn't allow me to add a continues border underneath both.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$output .= '<div class="property-details">';

foreach ( (array) $this->property_details as $label => $key ) {
$output .= sprintf( '<span class="label">%s</span><span class="value">%s</span>', $label, $value ) );
        }
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```